# why my batch script is printing "Missing Operator" as its first line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have decided to use a subroutine to improve on a current program of mine. I whipped it up in its own batch file to test it out and get it working correctly without screwing up my whole program, and I got it working save for one thing. For some reason, every time its run, it prints "Missing Operator" as its first line.

NOTE: I am aware that it is preforming the F to C conversion incorrectly. I am fixing that now.

[image: Subroutine as it is working now.]

I have no idea why this is, and I need it to not print any additional lines not only to not have the line int he program, but because each screen of the finished program has a set number of lines and columns that it will display at any one time. One extra line on a full page, and it will cut off parts of the screen which should be displayed.

The code for this subroutine (and the program I am using to test it) is:

```
@echo off

:1
cls
call :ferDesc
echo.
pause
goto 1

:ferDesc
echo off
set /a xsides=54
set /a fer=%random%%%xsides+59
set /a fer1=%fer%-32
set /a cels=%fer1%/1.8
if %fer% leq -40 goto td1
if %fer% leq -30 goto td2
if %fer% leq -20 goto td3
if %fer% leq -10 goto td4
if %fer% leq 0 goto td5
if %fer% leq 10 goto td6
if %fer% leq 20 goto td7
if %fer% leq 30 goto td8
if %fer% leq 40 goto td9
if %fer% leq 50 goto td10
if %fer% leq 60 goto td11
if %fer% leq 70 goto td12
if %fer% leq 80 goto td13
if %fer% leq 90 goto td14
if %fer% leq 100 goto td15
if %fer% leq 110 goto td16
if %fer% leq 120 goto td17
if %fer% leq 130 goto td18
if %fer% geq 131 goto td19
:td1
set td=polar
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td2
set td=artic
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td3
set td=bitterly cold
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td4
set td=very cold
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td5
set td=cold
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td6
set td=wintery
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td7
set td=icey
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td8
set td=frosty
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td9
set td=chilly
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td10
set td=brisk
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td11
set td=cool
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td12
set td=pleasent
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td13
set td=warm
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td14
set td=balmy
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td15
set td=sweaty
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td16
set td=stweltering
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td17
set td=feaverishly hot
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td18
set td=baking
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
:td19
set td=deadly hot
echo It is a %td% day.
echo (%fer% F - %cels% C)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post on missing operators http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/885945-missing-operator-batch-script.html Maybe this can help.

Comment: Thank you. The divide by 1.8 seems to be what screws it up, I simply have to tell it how to do the math with only whole numbers. Thanks dude!

Comment: Thanks could you tick the answer if you think it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Sintax errors in

```
set /a fer=%random% %% %xsides% + 59
```

Also, there are no decimals in batch arithmetic so this

```
set /a cels=%fer1%/1.8
```

Should be

```
set /a cels=%fer1% * 10 / 18
```

Comment: Thanks! Howeaver it preforms the conversion wrong if I use

    set /a cels=%fer1% * 18 / 10

the proper math is "%fer1% * 10 / 18. That aside, awesome help man!